# Do Javascript objects follow ascending order while storing and displaying keys?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I want to know if javascript objects follow ascending order while storing and displaying keys. As per my knowledge objects do not use indexing like arrays. But then is this standard javascript behavior to display keys in ascending order or it is how the v8 engine work internally. I read in a post that different runtimes behave differently. I tested this output in node and chrome both run v8 engine and giving the same sorted output:

```
function same(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  const obj1 = {};
  const obj2 = {};
  for (let val of arr1) {
    obj1[val] = (obj1[val] || 0) + 1;
  }
  for (let val of arr2) {
    obj2[val] = (obj2[val] || 0) + 1;
  }
  console.log(obj1);
  console.log(obj2);
}
let array1 = [4, 2, 3, 1, 2]; // both not sorted
let array2 = [16, 4, 9, 4, 1];

same(array1, array2);
```

It is giving this kind of output. You can see the keys are in a sorted manner in both objects.

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}
{1: 1, 4: 2, 9: 1, 16: 1}
```

Comment: Welcome! A good question but please do remember to do your best to look for other similar questions before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order